# Over ride Bootstrap 3 Navbar breakpoint at 768

Tags: breakpoints

I've read through the answers relating to my question but none addresses my specific issue. Given the number of menu items my site requires I have established four breakpoints 600, 800, 1020, and 1200. They work fine except that the 600-800 zone gets interrupted by the Bootstrap 768 breakpoint. What I would like to do is somehow just ignore the Bootstrap breakpoint. Any suggestion. You can see the problem on my test site at https://www.msholmes-test.org.

TIA for any assistance.
jdadwilson

Answer (score 0):

do some stuff hide your menu after 767px of width by CSS media query and then show your menu icon.. after that use jquery toggleClasss event.

Comment: My desired menu kicks in at 800px. Then the Bootstrap menu kicks in at 768 and overrides my menu. What can I hide? I want the Bootstrap menu gone, period.